# How do I make a "WorksheetFunction.VLookup" with another table

Tags: excel, vba

I need to load information from another book into an empty book and link this information to another book using VLookup

I managed to pull the information out of the book, but now how can I link it to another book? I don't understand how to address it, just by opening it? And how best to organize the mapping using For... to ? The current code refers only to the first source workbook.

```
Sub Curse()
Dim sPath As String, sFile_1 As String, sFile1_2 As String, sheet As String, x As Integer
sSheet = "Sheet1"
sFile_1 = "Form.xlsx"
sFile1_2 = "Date1.xlsx"

sPath = InputBox("Enter the path where the files were saved")

If sPath Like "*\" Then
Else
sPath = sPath & "\"
End If

With Range("A2:B22")
.Formula = "='" & sPath & "[" & sFile_1 & "]" & sSheet & "'!" & "A2"
.Value = .Value
End With

    
For i = 2 To 22 Step 1
Cells(i, 3) = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 1), Range("A1:C33"), 3)
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: You've managed to assign the `.Formula` so that it refers to another workbook, do the same with `"=VLOOKUP()"` instead of the `WorksheetFunction.VLookup`?